# How to add a monitor as an external/secondary monitor of an Android device

Tags: remote-access, external-display, secondary-display

I have an app on my Android device that does a remote desktop connection to a computer, so I am able to see the computer's screen on my phone. The problem is the remote screen resolution is automatically set to my phone's resolution, so I am seeing very little of that screen. What I hope to get is to cast this remote desktop app to a normal-sized computer screen and see the remote desktop with the resolution of this monitor. I want the monitor to act as a second monitor acts when it is added to a normal computer, ie. the OS detects the new device and its resolution and applies it to the image displayed on it.

I tried using an HDMI cable to connect the phone to a monitor, but the image on the phone is just stretched on the monitor without applying the resolution of the new monitor.

Any ideas on how I could achieve this?

Comment: Samsung devices have the [DeX](https://www.samsung.com/us/apps/dex/) mode which allows to use an externally connected monitor and show a UI similar to a common desktop OS. Android itself also seem to contain some sort of desktop feature but to my knowledge this feature is hidden as it not yet an official feature: https://devsjournal.com/android-12-desktop-mode.html